# How can I override a pre-defined face for light and dark backgrounds?

Tags: faces

I would like to use `set-face-attribute` to pick one of two colors for the foreground depending on whether the background of the current theme is light or dark.

The expected behavior is that the foreground changes automatically if I switch from a light background theme to a dark background theme or vice-versa.

Here is a use case:

I customize the face of `stripe-hl-line` as follows:

```el
 (set-face-attribute 'stripe-hl-line nil
                        :overline   "gray"
                        :underline  "gray"
                        :foreground "dodger blue")
```

But I would like to change the foreground based on just if the theme is light or dark. That way I don't have to worry about customizing that face in each theme.

Comment: That's something normally done in the theme definition.

Comment: Although it could get complicated, it seems like you could make use of the `color` library here.  You could probably get the rgb or hex value of the background face, determine some threshold value for "dark", and set the foreground accordingly.

Comment: @wasamasa Yes. But for some faces, I don't care about their color being specific to the theme. I have updated my question with an example face I want to customize.

Comment: @Dan What would be an appropriate hook to reevaluate the background hex?

Comment: this is the logic you can use  `    (defface changing-face
        '((((background dark))  :foreground "White")
        (t                    :foreground "Black"))
        :group      'x-mode-faces)`... Since if you want to use existing face, then you can add the middle 2 lines to the existing defface form.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Seeing `(background dark)` in various `defface` declarations is what made me think that there has to be an automated way to detect the background darkness. But I don't see anything like that in `set-face-attribute` definition. I don't want to tweak the `defface`s in the packages themselves as I would like to update them from the package manager. I tried overriding deffaces in my init but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @MadhavanKumar, I focused on deriving a solution based on `defface`.

I realized that I can't override an existing `defface` but I can always create my own background color sensitive `defface`. Then the only question was how to use my custom defface instead of the original.

I'll use the same example of overriding the `stripe-hl-line` face to walk through the solution. This face is defined in the package [`stripe-buffer`](https://github.com/sabof/stripe-buffer).

Here are the steps:

#### Step 1. Define your own `defface`

```el
(defface my/stripe-hl-line
  '((((background dark))  (:overline "gray" :underline "gray" :foreground "dodger blue"))
    (t                    (:overline "gray" :underline "gray" :foreground "red")))
  "Bold face for highlighting the current line in Hl-Line mode."
  :group 'stripe-buffer)
```

This will result in the foreground color of `my/stripe-hl-line` face being *dodger blue* for dark backgrounds and *red* for light backgrounds.

#### Step 2. Create a function to remap the face

The [`face-remap-add-relative`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html) function is used to remap an existing face to a new face. In this case, I am remapping the `stripe-hl-line` face to `my/stripe-hl-line`.

```el
(defun my/stripe-hl-line-face-remap ()
  (face-remap-add-relative 'stripe-hl-line 'my/stripe-hl-line))
```

#### Step 3. Do the remapping at appropriate location

From the `stripe-buffer` source, I see that the `hl-line` face is remapped to `stripe-hl-line` face. So we need to do our remapping after that remapping happens (which is in the [`stripe-listify-buffer`](https://github.com/sabof/stripe-buffer/blob/c252080f55cb78c951b19ebab9687f6d00237baf/stripe-buffer.el#L322-323) function definition).

So we do our remapping by advising `stripe-listify-buffer` using the [`:after`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-combinators.html) `advice` combinator.

```el
(advice-add 'stripe-listify-buffer :after #'my/stripe-hl-line-face-remap)
```

Done!

That said, it would have been awesome to directly use something like `set-face-attribute` to set faces based on the background darkness.